# Регулярное выражение для полной проверки email

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как составить регулярное выражение что бы:
пропускать логин email-а (до @) на русском или английском языке с цифрами или без или просто цифрами.

Пример корректных логинов:
123456
login
логин-1
login.3
login.3-67

Пример некорректных логинов:
логинlogin
.123456
123456-

домен (до @) только на английском языке, с присутствием 1 или максимум 2-а точками:

Пример корректных доменов:
i.ru
ru.name.ru

Пример некорректных доменов:
.ru
ru
ru.
ru.name.ru.ua
домен

Допустима длинна от 6 до 35 символов

Comment: На текущий момент единственной проверкой корректности адреса электронной почты является проверка наличия `@` в одном экземпляре. Иначе же можно не пропустить вполне валидные адреса.

Comment: Какие к примеру?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: Адрес почты не является регулярным. Таким образом полностью его проверить регулярным выражением невозможно. Если не ошибаюсь, то @ валидный символ в имени почтового ящика. Так что @ может быть в адресе сколь угодно много.

Comment: `На текущий момент единственной проверкой корректности адреса электронной почты является` отправка письма и ожидание подтверждения.

Answer (score 10):

требуемая маска выглядит вот так: 
`preg_match('/^((([0-9A-Za-z]{1}[-0-9A-z\.]{1,}[0-9A-Za-z]{1})|([0-9А-Яа-я]{1}[-0-9А-я\.]{1,}[0-9А-Яа-я]{1}))@([-A-Za-z]{1,}\.){1,2}[-A-Za-z]{2,})$/u', $item)`

разложим маску более детально (обратите внимание что маска разбитая на абзацы не работает, это сделано для читаемости)

```
'/
^( - параметр что маска начинается с начала текста
    (
        (  - этот блок отвечает за логин латиницей
            [0-9A-Za-z]{1} - 1й символ только цифра или буква
            [-0-9A-z\.]{1,} - в середине минимум один символ (буква, цифра, _, -, .) (не менее 1 символа)
            [0-9A-Za-z]{1} - последний символ только цифра или буква
        )
        | - параметр "или/или" выбирает блок "латиница" или "кирилица"
        (  - этот блок отвечает за логин кирилицей
            [0-9А-Яа-я]{1} - 1й символ только цифра или буква
            [-0-9А-я\.]{1,} - в середине минимум один символ (буква, цифра, _, -, .) (не менее 1 символа)
            [0-9А-Яа-я]{1} - последний символ только цифра или буква
        )
    )
    @ - обазятельное наличие значка разделяющего логин от домена
    (
        [-0-9A-Za-z]{1,} - блок может состоять из "-", цифр и букв (не менее 1 символа)
        \. - наличие точки в конце блока
    ){1,2} - допускается от 1 до 2 блоков по вышеукащанной маске (mail. , ru.mail.)
    [-A-Za-z]{2,} - блок описывайющий домен вехнего уровня (ru, com, net, aero etc) (не менее 2 символов)
)$ - параметр что маска заканчивается в конце текста
/u - параметр позволяющий работать с кирилицей
'
```

исходный код функции с проверкой вариантов:

```
    <?php
//------correct
$email[] = '123456@i.ru';
$email[] = '123456@ru.name.ru';
$email[] = 'login@i.ru';
$email[] = 'логин-1@i.ru';
$email[] = 'login.3@i.ru';
$email[] = 'login.3-67@i.ru';
$email[] = '1login@ru.name.ru';
//----- wrong
$email[] = '1login_@i.ru';
$email[] = '_login@i.ru';
$email[] = '_login@ru.name.ru';
$email[] = 'логинlogin@i.ru';
$email[] = 'loginлогин@i.ru';
$email[] = '.123456@i.ru ';
$email[] = '123456-@i.ru';
$email[] = '@123456@i.ru';
$email[] = '123456@.ru';
$email[] = '123456@ru';
$email[] = 'login@.ru';
$email[] = '123456@ru.name.ru.ua';
$email[] = '123456@i.ру';
$email[] = '123456@ru.name.ру';

foreach ($email as $item) {
    if (1 == preg_match(
        '/^((([0-9A-Za-z]{1}[-0-9A-z\.]{1,}[0-9A-Za-z]{1})|([0-9А-Яа-я]{1}[-0-9А-я\.]{1,}[0-9А-Яа-я]{1}))@([-0-9A-Za-z]{1,}\.){1,2}[-A-Za-z]{2,})$/u', $item) . '<br/>'){
        echo '"' . $item . '" : correct' . '<br/>';
    } else {
        echo '"' . $item . '" : non-correct' . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: копипаста или сами писали?

Comment: @pavel увы сам писал, т.к. встроенная валидация php не работает с кирилицей `if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "E-mail ($email) указан верно.";
}`

Comment: @StanFad Мне кажется, что ты срань какую-то написал... Там у тебя русские буквы допустимы до @, а это даже банальный input type='email' не пропустит...

Comment: @askobar рекомендую вам изучить матчасть перед тем как оставлять подобные комментарии https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_match('#^([\w]+\.?)+(?<!\.)@(?!\.)[a-zа-я0-9ё\.-]+\.?[a-zа-яё]{2,}$#ui', 'email.my.test123@email.my-site.ru');
```

Comment: для зоны (например .рф - будет .xn--p1ai) так же надо указать a-zа-я0-9ё\.-

Answer (score 0):

Эта регулярка:
1 - не пускает email c логином меньше 3 символа
2 - не пускает email с хостом больше чем 2-а поддомена
так будет лучше
`^((([0-9A-Za-z]{1}[-0-9A-z\.]{0,30}[0-9A-Za-z]?)|([0-9А-Яа-я]{1}[-0-9А-я\.]{0,30}[0-9А-Яа-я]?))@([-A-Za-z]{1,}\.){1,}[-A-Za-z]{2,})$`

Comment: «эта регулярка» — это вы про своё предложение или про чьё-то ещё? если про чьё-то — укажите, пожалуйста, про чьё именно (нажав [edit])

Answer (score 0):

([A-zА-я])+([0-9\-_\+\.])*([A-zА-я0-9\-_\+\.])*@([A-zА-я])+([0-9\-_\+\.])*([A-zА-я0-9\-_\+\.])*[\.]([A-zА-я])+

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]